# Prove that $(2^n-1)(3^n-1)$ is not a perfect square

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Prove that $(2^n-1)(3^n-1)$ is not a perfect square.

I have tried this problem for a few days already and I feel I am really far from solving it. Most of my approaches have been analyzing how many times 2 divides the number, and how many times 3 divides it, as well as various mods. I am starting to think the proof is going to be factoring on a weird field or something like that instead.

We can see that if $n$ is odd then $3^n-1$ is divisible by $2$ exactly one time so the exponent of $2$ in the prime factorization of the number is $1$ and thus it is not a perfect square. Furthermore by lifting the exponent lemma we know that since $n$ is even the exponent of $2$ in the prime factorization of $3^n-1$ is $3-1+v_2(2) = 2+v_2(n)$ so we need $v_2(n)$ to be even. Therefore it is greater tan or equal to $2$ i.e $4$ divides $n$.

Similarly by lifting we can see that the exponent of $3$ in $2^n-1$ is $1+v_3(n)$ so we have $v_3(n)$ is odd i.e $3$ divides $n$.

Therefore if the expression is a perfect square we must have $12|n$.

Comment: You should state clearly what your problem is/what kind of help you want.

Comment: There are several possible things we could do. Do you just want a complete proof, a hint a comment about whether what you've done is relevant or something I haven't imagined?

Comment: Well, we have
$$\Biggl(6^k-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^k-\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^k \Biggr)^2 <\left(2^{2k}-1\right)\left(3^{2k}-1\right)<\Biggl(6^k-\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{3}{2}\right)^k-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^k\Biggr)^2$$
for all $k=1,2,\ldots$.  Not sure if one can show that there is no integer between $6^k-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^k-\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^k$ and $6^k-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^k-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^k$ for any $k=1,2,\ldots$.

Comment: Thank you Batominovski. How did you come up with that bound?

Comment: Well, I used the Taylor expansion of $\sqrt{\frac{\left(2^{2k}-1\right)\left(3^{2k}-1\right)}{6^{2k}}}$ and got that it is bounded above by $$1-\frac{1}{2\cdot 3^{2k}}-\frac{1}{2\cdot 2^{2k}}\,.$$

Comment: I agree that the close-votes are hard to understand.

Comment: @Peter The [revision history](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1854268/revisions) could explain them.

Comment: @DanielFischer OK

Comment: This result was proved by Szalay in the 1990s. A link to a generalization by Walsh is http://mysite.science.uottawa.ca/gwalsh/slov1.pdf.

Comment: @MikeBennett Maybe you give a proof-sketch  ?

Comment: Context helps; where did you see this problem?

Comment: @MikeBennett  It's up to you, but it would be best if you posted the reference as an answer so that the thread is answered.

Answer (score 6):

That there are no solutions was proved by Szalay in 1997; a generalization to the equation
$$
(2^n-1)(3^m-1) = z^2
$$ 
was given by Walsh in 2000 or so :

http://mysite.science.uottawa.ca/gwalsh/slov1.pdf

The proof follows from elementary arguments about (binary) recurrence sequences and local considerations at the primes $2$ and $3$.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. How come you had it at your fingertip ?

Comment: Misspent youth, I suspect.

Comment: Are you a mathematician ?

Comment: On occasion! It keeps me out of trouble.